# I receive a 401 error when I access a custom method inside my Models folder

Tags: database, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using Loopback to access/update/make changes to my database.  I've created a method called deleteSingleHearingTest in my common/models folder:

```
Account.deleteSingleHearingTest = function (req, callback) {
    console.log('accounts.js: deleteSingleHearingTest: are we being reached????', req)
    Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
        .then(account => {
            if (!account) {
                throw new Error('Cannot find user');
            }
            console.log('account.js: deleteSingleHearingTest: req: ', req);
            return app.models.HearingTest.updateAll({ accountId: account.id, id: req.body.hearingTestId }, { isDeleted: new Date() });

        })
        .then(() => {
            callback(null);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            callback(error);
        });
}
```

after which I created a remote method:

```
Account.remoteMethod(
        'deleteSingleHearingTest', {
            http: {
                path: '/deleteSingleHearingTest',
                verb: 'post'
            },
            accepts: [
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } }
            ],
            returns: { "wtf": "wtf" }
        });
```

When I attempt to use this via fetch inside a method called deleteSingleHearingTest in my actions folder(redux) I receive a 401 status error message:

```
export const deleteSingleHearingTest = (hearingTestNumber) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let state = getState();
        if (!state.user || !state.user.accessToken || !state.user.accessToken.id || !state.user.accessToken.userId) {
            console.debug('writeTestResult', state.user);
            // TODO: ERROR
            return;
        }
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_SINGLE_REPORT_REQUEST
        });
        console.log('here is your access token', state.user.accessToken);

        fetch(SERVERCONFIG.BASEURL + '/api/Accounts/deleteSingleHearingTest?access_token=' + state.user.accessToken.id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: SERVERCONFIG.HEADERS,
            body: JSON.stringify({ "hearingTestId": hearingTestNumber })


        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log('actions/user.js deleteSingleReport were in the pipe 5x5', response.json());
                }
                console.log('actions/user.js failed to delete item: response: ', response)
            })
    }
};
```

Two errors I'm noticing:
1.  the Account.deleteSingleHearingTest never gets reached.  I know this because the console.log never shows up in the window where I ran node .

2. I get a 401 status error message on the front end.

Here is a picture of my StrongLoop gui.
[image]

here is the picture of my account.json file

Here's a picture of a method that a previous developer created that currently works with no status errors.  deleteSingleHearingTest is nearly identical.

[image]
[image]

Comment: returns `wtf` ha! ha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell by looking at your API Explorer screenshot, your `Account` model is extending LoopBack's built-in `User` model. The `User` model has ACLs configured to deny access to all methods except few explicitly allowed ones. You can find the ACL configuration in [common/models/user.json](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/be91ba3dadbf4e9a63de77a6725c1e6bf2888865/common/models/user.json#L25-L107).

```
"acls": [
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "create"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "deleteById"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "login"
  },
  // etc.
]
```

The first entry denies access to all methods, the subsequent entries allow access to certain methods for certain groups of users. For example, anybody (`$everyone`) can create a new user or invoke a `login` method, but the details of a User model can be retrieved only by the user themselves (`$owner`).

Please refer to [Controlling data access](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html) and [Understanding the built-in User model](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Managing-users.html#understanding-the-built-in-user-model) in LoopBack's documentation to learn more.

In order to allow your users to execute `Account.deleteSingleHearingTest` method, you need to add a new ACL entry to your `Account` configuration. I believe LoopBack can merge ACL defined in the base model (`User)` with the additional ACL entries defined in a subclassing model (`Account`) as of [pull request #1289](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1289). If that's the case then you need to simply add a new ACL entry in your `common/models/account.json` file. Assuming any logged-in user can invoke `deleteSingleHearingTest`, but anonymous (unauthenticated) users cannot:

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  "base": "User",
  // ...
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "deleteSingleHearingTest"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I've since updated my account.json file('ive upload a picture in the edit), but I'm still getting the same error.  I've restarted the server(just to make sure, but i'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: I figured out the problem:  For some reason I forgot the "$" before authenticated.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @VK1 you are welcome! Would you mind upvoting my answer? Also if I may: in the future, please paste the code into the answer and format it as code, don't upload screenshots. Source code as text is easier to read, copy out and quote in the answers.

Comment: No problem, I'll keep that in mind moving forward.  Upvoted